On the coefficients of the $j$-function
For the well-known $j$-function in the theory of modular forms, we can write
$$j(q)=\frac1q+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c(n)q^n,$$
where the coefficients $c(n)\ (n=0,1,\ldots)$ are positive integers. It is known that
$$c(0)=744,\ c(1)=196884,\ c(2)=21493760,\ c(3)=864299970.$$
In 1932, Petersson proved that
$$c(n)\sim\frac{e^{4\pi\sqrt n}}{\sqrt2 n^{3/4}}\ \ \ \text{as}\ n\to+\infty.$$
For the Fibonacci sequence $(F_n)_{n\ge0}$, Bugeaud, Mignotte and Siksek [Annals of Math. 163 (2006), 969-1018] proved that $F_n$ with $n>1$ is a perfect power if and only if $n\in\{6,12\}$.  Motivated by this, and Question 315828 and Question 484381,
here I pose the following conjecture.
Conjecture 1. $c(n)$ with $n\ge0$ can never be a perfect power.
Via Mathematica, I have verified that none of $c(0),c(1),\ldots,c(3000)$ is a perfect power.
QUESTION 1. Can one prove that $c(n)$ with $n\ge0$ is never a square?
Recall that a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge m}$ of real numbers is said to be log-concave if $a_n^2\ge a_{n-1}a_{n+1}$ for all $n>m$. My following conjecture is concerned with the log-concavity of the sequence $(c(n))_{n\ge0}$.
Conjecture 2. (i) The sequence $(c(n+1)/c(n))_{n\ge0}$ is strictly decreasing (to the limit $1$). For $c'(n)=c(n+1)/c(n)$, the sequence $(c'(n+1)/c'(n))_{n\ge1}$ is strictly increasing (to the limit $1$).
(ii) Define $b(n)=\root{n+1}\of{c(n+1)}/\root n\of{c(n)}$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Then the sequence $(b(n))_{n\ge1}$ is strictly increasing (to the limit $1$). Moreover, the sequence
$(b(n+1)/b(n))_{n\ge1}$ is strictly decreasing (to the limit $1$).
QUESTION 2. Can one prove that the sequence $(c(n))_{n\ge0}$ is log-concave?
Recall that a polynominal sequence $(P_n(q))_{n\ge0}$ is called $q$-log-concave if for each $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ all the coefficients of the polynomial $P_n(q)^2-P_{n-1}(q)P_{n+1}(q)$ are nonnegative.
Conjecture 3. For $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, define
$$P_n(q)=\sum_{k=0}^nc(k)q^k\ \ \text{and}\ \ j_n(q)=\frac1q+\sum_{k=0}^nc(k)q^k.$$
Then the polynomial sequence $(P_n(q))_{n\ge0}$ is $q$-log-concave.
Also, for each positive integer $n$, all the coefficients of the polynomial $j_n(q)^2-j_{n-1}(q)j_{n+1}(q)$ are nonnegative.
QUESTION 3. Are there any helpful ideas towards proving Conjecture 3?
Your comments are welcome!

The "circle method" gives an asymptotic formula for c(n) that should reduce your "conjecture 2" and "question 2" to a routine finite computation.

As $c(n-1),c(n),c(n+1)$ are involved, knowing the main term of $c(n)$ is not enough for proving Conjecture 2. One needs a refined control of the error term.

The Hardy-Ramanujan(-Rademacher) method gives you more than you need, with an error term of order some small power of n times the square root of c(n).
